# SSAS comparing previous rows data and get the count

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I have following Scenario in cube

| ID | PreID | Code | Valid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -1 | A | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | B | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | B | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | B | 1 |

Id compared with PreID.
First Row ID 1 does not have Preid and Code is A so valid is 0. This is correct

Second Row ID 2 and Preid  is 1 , code is B for ID 2 but code is A for ID 1 so valid is 0. This is correct

Third Row Id is 3 and Preid is 1 , code is B for for id 3 but Code is A for Id 1 so valid should be 0 but displaying 1 which is incorrect

Fourth Row Id is 4 and Preid is 1, code is B for for id 3 and Code is B for Id 2 so valid is 1 which is correct.

Trying to get valid 0 for third row.

All of them are dimensions and  valid is measure.

Is it possible to compare the Code column of Key and pre key without adding new dimension ? currently it is looking at the Code column of only Key and not prekey and setting the valid 0 or 1.
I have tried previousmember but as shown in example there will not be consistent rows of previousmemeber

Comment: If I could guess, adding a new dimension column with the value of "previous member", would make it simpler. i.e., alter your dimension table and populate it with data for the previous member as part of your dimension building process. This is assuming you have control over changing the dimension. You can mark your new added column as hidden if you don't want to expose it to the users.

Comment: @Subbu   Thank you for your response. Yes, adding the extra dimension was my option. But want to know if there is any other option other than adding a dimension.